# add line break between 2 variables

Tags: php

I am echoing back these 2 variables in to a table, but wanted to know how to add a line break between these 2?

```
echo $row ['username'] . $row ['date_time'];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you're printing an HTML output to your browser:

```
 echo $row["username"]."<br />".$row["date_time"];
```

EDIT:

when printing to HTML -  you better print the variables after passing them through `htmlspecialchars` function in order to avoid Cross-site-scripting ([XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)), I'll do it this way:

```
 echo htmlspecialchars($row["username"],ENT_QUOTES)."<br />".htmlspecialchars($row["date_time"],ENT_QUOTES);
```

if you want to print it to a file or something similar:

```
 echo $row["username"]."\n".$row["date_time"];
```

Answer (score 2):

you can always echo normal html from php.

```
echo "<div id=\"mydiv\"> Div content goes here </div>";
```

note the backslashes for double quotes wrapping mydiv to escape them.
so you can add a 
 tag in between them to get a new line.

```
echo $row["username"] . "<br />" . $row["date_time"];
```