# Combine two textarea value with line breaks using PHP

Tags: php, textarea

I have two different `textarea` and I want to store that both in one field of database with line breaks. Its working good if I store one `textarea` value in table field, But I need to store both `textarea` value in one field.

Example :-

textaera 1)

```
Hello
text from textarea1
```

textarea 2)

```
How are you?
its second textarea text
```

Output that I need with all line breaks and also between two `textarea` value :-

```
Hello
text from textarea1
How are you?
its second textarea text
```

Comment: Use `\r\n` to denote line break

Comment: `$combined = $textarea1 . PHP_EOL . $textarea2;` Use `nl2br($combined)` if you want to output the line-breaks in HTML.

Comment: To output in HTML, use: `preg_replace("/\r\n/","<br />",$string);`

Comment: If you want to keep the references, it may be better to use something like `serialize()` on the db side then `unserialize()` and `implode()` when output back to browser

Comment: I can combine using PHP_EOL but can not display value with linebreaks..

Comment: @Rasclatt can you explain me more or place your answer with code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you both values are coming into variables `$textarea1 and $textarea2` correspondingly. You can do it like below:-

```
$combine_data = $textarea1."\n".$textarea2;
```

OR

```
$combine_data = $textarea1 . PHP_EOL . $textarea2; and use nl2br($combined) to show it again in text-area //@iainn suggestion
```

OR

```
$combine_data = $textarea1 ."<br/>". $textarea2;
```

Reference Taken :-

[add line break between 2 variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953378/add-line-break-between-2-variables)

Comment: I have only one field from the database not like your answer $textarea1 and $textarea2

Comment: Man. from the two text-area get the value first and then concatenate them according to the third solution and then save it to the db. When you again fetch and show it to text-area due to `"<br/>"` automatically line break will shown.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, if you want to be able to retrieve the blocks separately (for greater flexibility) but store both in one column, you can use `serialize()`:

**To store the data:**

```
$data = array('p1'=>$_POST['textarea1'], 'p2'=>$_POST['textarea2']);
$compress = serialize($data);
//insert value $compress into one column in your database
```

**To recall the data:**

```
// Get column from database 
$data = $row['db_column'];
$decompress = unserialize($data);
// Echo to browser using html break and End Of Line constant (for compatibility)
echo implode('<br />'.PHP_EOL,$decompress);
```

You can also echo each value separately after unserializing:

```
echo  $decompress['p1'].'<br />'.PHP_EOL.
      $decompress['p2'].'<br />'.PHP_EOL;
```

By doing it this way, you can recall the data in their respective blocks, that way if you decide to change something later, you still have all the raw data in blocks.